What does "Two rolls" quote really mean?
In Sweet Smell of Success (1957), the paperboy is selling his newspapers on the side of the road:

Paperboy: - You want a hot item on Hunsecker's column? Two rolls got
fresh with the baker.

What does "Two rolls" quote really mean?

In the script it's "Iggy: Hey, Fresh, the Globe just came in -- Hey, Sidney, want an item for Hunsecker's column?  Two rolls get fresh with a baker!  Hey, hot, hot, hot -- etc.

It's a double pun. Obviously Sidney, being a press agent with a direct line to the Hunsecker Column, would be interested in a recent news story about a local businessman caught in some sort of heated argument with two monied individuals (pimps?), but Iggy is making a joke at his expense, one which Sidney doesn't find especially amusing.

'Roll' is ambiguous. It could either be a person flashing around a large bankroll or a literal bread roll.

'Got fresh' is ambiguous. It can either mean acting arrogantly (and by implication causing a fracas) or something that is brand new.


Lehman (who wrote the source novella) uses it in this context.

I grunted. “Since when does he bother to see the performers he
praises?”
“Don’t get fresh,” she pouted. Then she smiled quickly. “After all, he
is my boss, and I do take my life in my hands letting you come up here
to see the column in advance.”

The newsie also claims this story is 'hot, hot, hot'. But again, it's the bread rolls that are being pulled fresh and warm from the oven by the fictional baker, not that the story is of great interest to the public.

You could make a similar joke by saying something like "I heard an interesting story, it's just above the ground floor!"


Two rolls got fresh with the baker

In "urban" language, it means that 2 girls (sweet rolls) had sex with the same man.
In the movie, J.J. Hunsecker wants to "protect" his younger sister and control her life. He wants to end her relationship with Steve. By gossiping and threatening, he pulls every string he can. The story on the frontpage could be about the affair Leo Bartha (J. J.'s main competitor and prominent columnist too) has (or any other).

Sidney attempts to blackmail Leo at Toots Shor's Restaurant and Lounge by threatening to expose his marital infidelity with Rita unless Leo prints an item stating that Steve is a Communist who smokes marijuana. Instead, Leo chooses exposure over compromising his journalistic integrity, which even his wife Loretta praises as his first decent act in years. He then bribes columnist Otis Elwell, who agrees to print the item if Sidney will arrange for him to receive a sexual favor from an "available" woman. At his apartment, Rita balks at the implications of getting acquainted with Otis, but ultimately assents to Sidney's plan in order to stay employed. The next morning, the smear appears in Otis's column and the combo is fired.

The character played by Burt Lancaster is based upon Walter Winchell:

He uncovered both hard news and embarrassing stories about famous people by exploiting his exceptionally wide circle of contacts, first in the entertainment world and the Prohibition era underworld, then in law enforcement and politics. He was known for trading gossip, sometimes in return for his silence. His outspoken style made him both feared and admired. Novels and movies were based on his wisecracking gossip columnist persona...


I don't think this is right. The newsie isn't telling him about a story in the paper, he's telling his client (a newsman) about a potential story that he could put in his column.

In the original script it's "Hey, Sidney, want an item for Hunsecker's column?, e.g. to  be inserted. I'm not sure why they changed the line in the film, but the meaning appears to be the same.
